# wrong vhost configuration in /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf

Tags: linux, apache, vhosts

My vhost configuration at `/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf` looks like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *

<VirtualHost *>
        ServerName www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *> 
    ServerName en.example.com 
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/english
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *> 
        ServerName photo.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/photo
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *> 
        ServerName music.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/music
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *> 
        ServerName video.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/video
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, only `www.example.com` is showing the correct site at `/var/www/html/site`. All other subdomains are giving a `500 internal server error`. What am i doing wrong?

---

***UPDATE:***
i am really sorry guys... my Domain Name guy confirmed to me that my domain names were routed correctly to my IP address.... only after i did a `dig en.example.com` (something i should have done a lot earlier) did i realize that my Domain Name guys made a stupid misconfiguration... the web addresses were not even reaching my IP address to begin with... really sorry for the trouble folks :( :( - this `vhost.conf` file is all right

Comment: Did you enable the new websites with `a2ensite`? Also is good practice to use separate files for different virtual-hosts.

Comment: i didn't use any a2ensite

Comment: Well basically it depends on the distro that you are using. But debian based distros use a file system that under /etc/apache2 you have a folder sites-available, where you should create a .conf file per host. Then when you execute the come a2ensite it creates a symlink in another folder called sites-enabled that is the one to enables the Vhost. then you just need to reload the apache service.

Comment: go through [apache docs :: VirtualHost Examples](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html)

Comment: i am really sorry guys... my Domain Name guy confirmed to me that my domain names were routed correctly to my IP address.... only after i did a `dig en.example.com` (something i should have done a lot earlier) did i realize that my Domain Name guys made a stupid misconfiguration... the web addresses were not even reaching my IP address to begin with... really sorry folks :( :(

Answer (score 1):

```
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80

# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName en.example.com 
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/english
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80> 
        ServerName photo.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/photo
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80> 
        ServerName music.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/music
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80> 
        ServerName video.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/video
</VirtualHost>
```